# Laravel Queues not writing to db

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

So I am just starting out with laravel queues. I have a job that is just logging something for me to see. The queue driver is database.

The job runs,But the queue does not add any db entries.

I have so far tried

stopping the server after a delayed job is added -> php artisan config:clear -> php artisan config:cache -> restarting before the job runs

The job runs fine, but I can see no entries in the jobs table

What could be missing here?

here are the connections from queue.php

'connections' => [

```
    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ]
```

]

Comment: The `jobs` table lists all your *queued* jobs. You aren't seeing any jobs in the table because they have already executed successfully like you said. Once a job runs successfully it is removed from the `jobs` table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jobs table is not there for you to know which jobs ran, it is there to be a place where the workers can pick up jobs from. If it fails, it will be put into failed_jobs.

To get an overview of which jobs is running, Laravel developers often choose the `Laravel` queue package [Horizon](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=laravel%20horizon) (which is a wrapper for a redis driver). This requires redis, which can be hard to setup but the dashboard feature it comes with is a great tool.

[image]

Comment: Is there a package that can help me write the start and end times etc to a table, maybe a separate one?

Comment: Not that i know off often when you want that info you save it to a related model.